# Getting the sum of columns in a Laravel raw select statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get the sum of the records that are returned in a Laravel select statement but I can't seem to get it right.

My original statement is as follows;

```
$results = DB::table('polls')->select('polls.id as poll_id', 'poll_votes.vote_count as vote_count', 'poll_options.id as poll_option_id')
    ->join('poll_options','polls.id','=','poll_options.poll_id')
    ->join('poll_votes', 'poll_options.id', '=', 'poll_votes.poll_option_id')
    ->where([['polls.status','=','1'], ['poll_options.status','=','1'],])
    ->get();
```

I have tried adding the following after the last element on the `->select` line but I keep getting errors;

```
DB::raw('sum(poll_votes.vote_count) total_votes')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's the error? Also, is `groupBy` relevant in your context?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error you are receiving, use the `groupBy` before your `->get` method:

```
->groupBy('polls.id');
```

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column

Comment: Hey, So I added the groupBy like you said on my original statement, without the DB::raw statement, and im still getting an error; `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'poll_votes.vote_count' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Answer (score 0):

You want the sum of Colum or Count all the records: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#aggregates